# Extension of Simple Random Sample without Replacement

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions, sampling

First, I will show an extension of simple random sample without replacement, and then put forward the question.

(1)

From Wiki, a simple random sample is a subset of individuals (a sample) chosen from a larger set (a population), where each individual is chosen randomly and entirely by chance, such that each individual has the same probability of being chosen at any stage during the sampling process.

Now, suppose that **each individual in the population has a different weight representing the chance of being sampled**.

Take the following example:

The population is {1, 2, 3, 4}, and the relative weights of the individual 1, 2, 3, 4 are 1, 2, 3, 4 for concise. Then if a sample {1, 2} is taken from the population without replacement. Then the possibility of the sample {1, 2} should be calculated by:

$\frac{1}{1 + 2 + 3 + 4} * \frac{2}{2 + 3 + 4} +　\frac{2}{1 + 2 + 3 + 4} * \frac{1}{1 + 3 + 4}$.

(2)

My question is how to give out a general expression of the possibility for a sample taken in the above way? If there doesn't exist an closed form, how to approximate it?

Answer (score 0):

Extended comment:

I don't know if it helps with your particular application, but
this kind of sampling is exactly implemented in the `sample`
function of R statistical software, using the `prob` argument.

For your example, it would be `sample(1:4, 2, prob=1:4)`.

A million draws made to these specifications give a 1 and a 2
(in either order) 4.74% of the time. This agrees to two places
with your computation $(2/90 + 2/80) = 0.04722222.$

```
 m = 10^6;  hit = logical(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {
  x = sample(1:4, 2, prob=1:4)
  hit[i] = (sum(x)==3) }
 mean(hit)
 ## 0.047389

 2/90 + 2/80
 ## 0.04722222
```

Notes: (a) In R, `1:4` (consecutive integers) is shorthand for the vector `c(1,2,3,4)`. 
(b) The 4-vector for the argument `prob` need not sum to unity because
R normalizes it before use. (c) See R documentation and a reference on the sample function by typing `? sample` in the session window. (d) In symbols, the sum 1 + 3 + 4
might be written $\sum_{1, i\ne 2}^4 i.$

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of the multivariate Wallenius' [noncentral hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_hypergeometric_distributions).

In R, the [BiasedUrn package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BiasedUrn/index.html) says it can calculate these (with approximations for some of the functions), though it calls the weights "odds" which may be confusing.  It produces the same result for your example:

```
library(BiasedUrn)
dMWNCHypergeo(x=c(1,1,0,0), m=c(1,1,1,1), n=2, odds=c(1,2,3,4))
# 0.04722222
1/(1+2+3+4) * 2/(2+3+4) + 2/(1+2+3+4) * 1/(1+3+4) 
# 0.04722222
```